# Are unquoted data URIs valid in CSS?

Tags: css, w3c-validation, data-uri

```
#something {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,ABCDEF);
}
```

This snippet **works** in all browsers which support data URIs (obviously with something else than ABCDEF).

Also, it's valid according to [the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri):

> ...**optional** single quote (') or double quote (") character followed by the URI itself...

But the [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) won't accept it without quotes:

> Value Error : background url(data:image/png;base64,ABCDEF) is an incorrect URL

If you surround the URI with single or double quotes, it validates.

Am I missing something? Is it a bug in the validator? **EDIT**: [it was](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/42)!

Comment: You should update your question: it was a bug in the validator, that is now patched. Cf. the discussion at https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/42

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as the URI itself does not break the `url()` syntax in any way (e.g. `(` and `)` must either be escaped or URI-encoded so they don't prematurely end the function token, also mentioned in the spec), it should be valid even if unquoted.

It's probably a validator bug. Specifically, it doesn't appear to handle unquoted data URIs in any form, because when I simply change `data` to `http` (even though it obviously doesn't resemble a typical HTTP address):

```
#something {
    background: url(http:image/png;base64,ABCDEF);
}
```

... it then magically passes validation.

Comment: Agreed. If the spec defines it as optional, then unless there's something else saying it needs to be different for the data scheme, then the issue is with the validator if it fails your markup for missing them.

Comment: I opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/42#issuecomment-155572400).